# How to send EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE keyevent using uiautomator

Tags: android, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I want to send `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE` on an `EditText` using uiautomator:

Code to test:

```
mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                //Do something
                }
}
```

this should be tested sending the numpad keycode for enter - however this differs from normal KeyCodes as below:

```
   mDevice.pressKeyCode(KEYCODE_ENTER);
```

All keyevents to confirm are not working here. How to achieve sending a numpad confrim where the keyevent will be `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE`?